# Browsing/Navigation in Google Chrome with the keyboard

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i would like to navigate through a tutorial website and mark the stated code with my keyboard and without the mouse. (for copying and pasting to my editor) i love to use the keyboard extensively.
i know i once had an extension installed that supported the cursor keyboard navigation. but unfortunately i forgot how the extension was named or if i used this with firefox.
i searched a while and tried different extensions. but i couldn't find it.
is there anybody who could help me find a solution?